# Boolean expressions and control flow involving manipulating index numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, boolean-expression, control-flow

Tried this in Python as part of a function, and predictably, it did not work:

```
outputlist = [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,-2,-1,0,2,4,-3,-2,1,0,2]    

def counter(outputlist):
    outputlistcut = outputlist[:5]
    count = 0
    for i in np.arange(len(outputlistcut)):
        if outputlistcut[i] >= 0 and outputlistcut[i-1] < 0:
            count += 1
    return count 

count = counter(outputlist)
```

This returned the error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'range' and 'int'
```

Basically, I want to count the number of instances the output f(x) of a function (the f(x) being recorded in `outputlist` passes or equals 0 after becoming more positive from a negative y. A bit stuck on how I can concisely execute this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `outputlist`?

Comment: if I copied and pasted that I suspect I would see a name error ... not a TypeError

Comment: I neglected to mention that I defined outputlist earlier. Editing my post.

Comment: What is the value of `i`?

Comment: what is in outputlist?

Comment: It is the output of a function; I'll fill it in with nonsense example numbers for now.

Comment: I think you are neglecting things ... your issue cannot be reproduced with this code ... please provide code that can reproduce the problem

Comment: somewhere in your code you are doing something like `range(100) - 1`

Comment: if I copy and paste your sample code I get no errors ... and I get `count` = 2 .. again if you want help you have to give us code that reproduces the error ...

Comment: Joran, I just edited my post above and did my best to extract out of a really bloated script. I am still getting the same error. If so, there could be something going on outside this chunk of code, but the Python interpreter is telling me that the error is in the function.

Comment: @potpie there is still no error if I copy and paste your updated code ...(see https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93e93b5066ec8e2c37b3)

Comment: it is in the function but the source is coming from outputlist, print outputlist inside that function to see what is there before the error

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That was the problem -- it looks like after I initially defined `outputlist`, I accidentally do `outputlist = range(outputlist)` later on. Thanks for your help. Looks like the error was not from the function itself.

Comment: no worries, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you did (based on the error you are recieving)

```
i = range(N)
```

this is wrong

I suspect you want something like

```
count = 0
for i in range(N):
    if outputlist[i-1] < 0 and outputlist[i] == 0:
        count += 1
```

although there are lots of better ways of doing this

```
count = sum([a<0 and b==0 for a,b in zip(outputList,outputList[1:])])
```

Comment: I did what you had, I just left it out. I had my i in a for loop.

Comment: well the only minus you have in what you show is `i-1` it(the TypeError) is telling you it cannot subtract an int from a range ... so i is becoming a range at some point ... you need to put a complete code example that demonstrates your issue if someone were to copy and paste it

Comment: Joran, I tried your list comprehension in my code, and unfortunately, it does not work for me. No errors, but I am getting count = 0. Do I have to put a * in front of the lists, or anything like that?

Comment: Caught another personal typo and it now works, thanks.